# gulp.src() looks just push once as a readable stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Look at the following code.The test.html's size is `1.86MB`,But when run the code the console output:1 1.That looks the `gulp.src()` just call push() once to send the whole file whatever how large the file is.So that do not utilize the stream's advantage.
OR I am wrong,the gulp has a much big buffer in it.

```
let through = require('through2');
let fs = require('fs');
let gulp = require('gulp');
let path = require('path');

gulp.task('default', [], function () {
    let i = 1;
    let j = 1;
    gulp.src(path.join(__dirname, './test/test.html'))
        .pipe(through.obj(function (chunk, enc, callback) {
            console.log(i++);
            this.push(chunk)
            callback()
        })).pipe(through.obj(function (chunk, enc, callback) {
        console.log(j++);
        callback()
    })).on('finish', function () {
        console.log('finished' + i);
    })
})
```